# Update with replace using values from another table without joining

Tags: sql

I need to update a column using replace to find any instance of a string to replace it with another. the old and new strings are stored in a seperate table. How can I perform the update?

I have tried variations of this:

```
update srctable 
  set value = REPLACE(value,t.oldstring,t.newstring)
  from (select distinct oldstring,newstring from exttable) as t
```

Comment: Please consider sharing an example of what the data might look like and what the expected outcome is.

Comment: what's the issue with using a join?